# How to change the whole values of DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe

At first attempt, I want to create a DataFrame but forgot to put some values:

```
a=[0,1/4,2/4,3/4,4]
b=[0,1/4,2/4,3/4,4]
z=DataFrame(index=a,columns=b)
```

Then I got this.

```
>      0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 4.00
> 0.00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
> 0.25  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
> 0.50  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
> 0.75  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
> 4.00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I want to replace all of values by `np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)`

Then I tried this:

```
z.values=np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
```

Result:

> object.**setattr**(self, name, value)
>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute

I mean I could re-create the DataFrame with values in it but it seems to be very .... ( dont know how to say).

**Question:**

1/ Why I can not do it ?

2/ How to solve it ?

3/ On the condition that I want every single values of `z.values` would be the result of multiplication of columns and rows(rows * columns). How can I do it ?

**Expected result of 3/**

```
     0.00    0.25   0.50    0.75 4.00
0.00    0       0      0       0    0
0.25    0  0.0625  0.125  0.1875    1
0.50    0   0.125   0.25   0.375    2
0.75    0  0.1875  0.375  0.5625    3
4.00    0       1      2       3   16
```

Comment: What is the output you expect? Please let me know. And BTW what you mean by your third point?

Comment: @Amazing Things Around You the values is (row * columns). mate !

Comment: But you have shown this: `np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)`

Comment: I know, I mean just in case of that how can I do it easily ?

Comment: Did you mean something like the one I updated in the answer?

Comment: Absolutetly, thanks mate !

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194148/discussion-between-chau-loi-and-amazing-things-around-you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.where` is one way to go:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a=[0,1/4,2/4,3/4,4]
b=[0,1/4,2/4,3/4,4]
z=pd.DataFrame(index=a,columns=b)

z.where(pd.notna,np.arange(25).reshape(5,5))
```

Output:

```
     0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 4.00
0.00    0    1    2    3    4
0.25    5    6    7    8    9
0.50   10   11   12   13   14
0.75   15   16   17   18   19
4.00   20   21   22   23   24
```

For the last one, use `np.matmul`:

```
mat = np.matmul(np.reshape(z.index, (-1,1)), np.reshape(z.columns, (1,-1)))
z.where(pd.notna, mat)
```

Output:

```
     0.00    0.25   0.50    0.75 4.00
0.00    0       0      0       0    0
0.25    0  0.0625  0.125  0.1875    1
0.50    0   0.125   0.25   0.375    2
0.75    0  0.1875  0.375  0.5625    3
4.00    0       1      2       3   16
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> z
     0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 4.00
0.00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
0.25  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
0.50  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
0.75  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4.00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
>>> def cross_mul(x):
...     return x.index * x.name
... 
>>> z.apply(cross_mul)
      0.00    0.25   0.50    0.75  4.00
0.00   0.0  0.0000  0.000  0.0000   0.0
0.25   0.0  0.0625  0.125  0.1875   1.0
0.50   0.0  0.1250  0.250  0.3750   2.0
0.75   0.0  0.1875  0.375  0.5625   3.0
4.00   0.0  1.0000  2.000  3.0000  16.0
>>> z.apply(lambda x: x.index * x.name) // One Liner
```

Comment: Thanks, @ChauLoi. If you find it useful please accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5))
>>> df
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
>>> a=[0,1/4,2/4,3/4,4]
>>> b=[0,1/4,2/4,3/4,4]
>>> df.columns = a
>>> df.index = b
>>> df
      0.00  0.25  0.50  0.75  4.00
0.00     0     1     2     3     4
0.25     5     6     7     8     9
0.50    10    11    12    13    14
0.75    15    16    17    18    19
4.00    20    21    22    23    24
```

**UPDATED**
A little easy one:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5),index=a,columns=b)
>>> df
      0.00  0.25  0.50  0.75  4.00
0.00     0     1     2     3     4
0.25     5     6     7     8     9
0.50    10    11    12    13    14
0.75    15    16    17    18    19
4.00    20    21    22    23    24
```

Comment: If I create a DataFrame first with no values, can I add values to it latter as I asked ? @Amazing Things Around You

Comment: So you want to create the dataframe first. But you have to keep the index in mind and then fill the respective values, in it. Let me edit